# Where does picasso (android image library) store the images?

Tags: picasso

Sorry about this silly question. Under which folder in the android file system does picasso cache the images? I'm using picasso 2.5.2

Answer (score 0):

context.getApplicationContext().getCacheDir(), picasso-cache